# Swift UIFont problems with characters "ch"

Tags: swift, string, uilabel, uifont

I'm using a font called Century Schoolbook Normal with text in a UILabel with a UIFont.. I notice whenever I insert the characters "ch" in a string I run into problems for example.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 ) )
label.text = "afgssdfdsdspopaopfsadffsdafdsfds"
label.backgroundColor = .green
label.font = UIFont(name: "Century-Schoolbook-Normal", size: 30 )
view.addSubview( label )
```

produces the image on my IPAD

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJZUf.png*

while if i enter into that string a ch anywhere it cuts off where i put it.. For example the below

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 ) )
label.text = "afgssdfdsdschpaopfsadffsdafdsfds"
label.backgroundColor = .green
label.font = UIFont(name: "Century-Schoolbook-Normal", size: 30 )
view.addSubview( label )
```

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCIsd.png*

This doesn't happen when i use another font. It works correctly. So how can I fix this and why does it happen? Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like your font file has a problem with character c. Try to download font file from different source and insert into your project.

Comment: tried it and same problem.. The width is 1024 which is plenty of space. an unusual thing happens though when i just enter the string "sdschpao". Then I get this http://i.imgur.com/h5R7err.png. ch produces the error consistently. It has unexpected behavior

Comment: can you try setting numberOFLines to 0 for your UILabel to get an exact idea and also set height of label to cover whole screen?

Comment: the height of the label is the entire screen as is the width. Here's a picture of a test project with the code. No other code throughout the project. The font type is included in info.plist and is called century2.ttf. This code yields the same problem above. http://i.imgur.com/pgTUBtv.png

Comment: ok please run the project now and post the screenshot of ipad screen

Comment: So it looks like your font file has a problem with character c. Try to download font file from different source and insert into your project.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried downloading another century schoolbook font from 2 websites. 1 website had the same problem and the other website had a variation of the font that seems to work..

Comment: You are welcome. You can always vote the answer and comment. It will help me to increase my score. Thanks

Comment: your answer is not posted except in comments. If you post it I will mark it as correct and upvote it.

Comment: just updaetd my answer